# String.split() para separar en los espacios, pero sin remplazar espacios

Tags: java, regex

Tengo un String como el siguiente:

```
String foo = "soy un texto"
```

Al aplicar la siguiente función:

```
String []  bar = foo. split(" ");
```

Lo separa en tres textos:

> ```
> "soy", "un" y "texto"
> ```

Sin embargo, yo quiero que **mantenga los espacios** como el siguiente ejemplo:

> ```
> "soy",  " un"  y " texto"
> ```

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: `string.split(String regex)` puede hacer maravillas para ti, dado que usa un regex para separar los segmentos, pero tu tienes que definir exactamente que formato quieres al fin. En tu ejemplo queda ambiguo donde quieres mantener los espacios y donde no.

Comment: Los quiero mantener en todas las palabras que tengan un espacio a su izquierda.

Comment: En tu ejemplo, "texto" tiene un espacio a su izquierda.

Comment: Estaba mal mi ejemplo, ya lo edité.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con las especificaciones aclarados la regex que puedes usar en `split` es:

```java
String foo = "Soy un texto";
String[] bar = foo.split("(?=\\s)");
for (String foobar : bar ){
    System.out.println(String.format("<%s>", foobar));
}
```

`(?=X)` te hace un *match* de lugares seguidos por un espacio, sin consumir caracteres.

Resultado:

```
<Soy>
< un>
< texto>
```

Comment: Vale aclarar que `\s` coincide con `[ \t\n\r\f]` y si sólo se quiere que coincida con espacios, sería con el espacio como literal dentro de la [inspección positiva](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special): `(?= )`

Answer (score 4):

Podemos agregar un elemento que nos servira como identificador para hacer el `split` por ejemplo:

```
String foo = "soy un texto";

foo = foo.replace(" ", "☺ ");//remplazamos por un caracter que no tenga la cadena
//y dejamos el espacio   ^ en blanco    
String []  bar = foo.split("☺");//y despues usamos el caracter
```

Esto da

```
"soy"
" un"
" texto"
```

---

Si queremos el espacio a la derecha  cambiamos nuestro remplace por `.replace(" ", " -")`

Que daria :

```
"soy "
"un "
"texto"
```

Comment: Sería un problema si el texto contiene algún `-`. Por supuesto, se podría cambiar por otro(s) caracter(es), pero siempre habría un caso que lo haría fallar.

Comment: @Mariano Podriamos cambiar el caracter `-` es es común por `☺` Mucho menos comun. O agregar un patrón `☺-☺-☺`

Answer (score 2):

puedes agregárselo tu mismo después de hacer el split

```
for(int i = 0;i < bar.length; i++) {
    if(i != 0) { //para que no se lo agregue al primer split
        bar[i] = " " + bar[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: En vez de verificar `i != 0`, ¿no convendría iniciar el `for` con `int i = 1`?